# Возможно ли отключить canvas для tiles?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, canvas

Возможно ли полностью отключить элемент canvas для рендеринга тайлов карты и использовать стандартные элементы с background-image?

Comment: Добавьте [mcve], покажите что вы пытались сделать, и что у вас не получается

Answer (score 1):

В JS API Яндекс карт такой функциональности нет.